# arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--cref'; did you mean '--xref'?

Tags: gcc, linker

I am using  arm-none-eabi-gcc for STM32 
I am trying to generate cross-reference table by passing option '--cref' to the linker, but I get  this error

```
arm-none-eabi-gcc: error: unrecognized command line option '--cref'; did you mean '--xref'?
```

is '--xref' a replacement for '--cref' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`--cref` is an option for the [GNU binutils linker](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/ld/Options.html#Options), `ld`, but it is not an option of [`gcc`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Option-Summary.html#Option-Summary)

You can direct `gcc` to pass such options through to `ld` when it invokes the linker by using the the
`gcc` option `-Wl`, which has the usage:

```
-Wl,<ld-option>[,<ld-option>...]
```

So, instead of `--cref`, pass `-Wl,--cref` in your `gcc` commandline.

By itself, this will make the linker print the cross-reference table on the standard output. If you
would prefer to have it in a mapfile, then request a mapfile from the linker as well and the cross-reference
table will be appended to it: `-Wl,--cref,-Map=mapfile`

(`--xref` was an option for `gcc` long ago. It is not longer one, but the commandline
parser will still suggest it as one that you might have meant when it parses an unknown
option.)